# Merge list of dictionaries with the same key

Tags: python-3.x, list, merge

I have a list of dictionaries where I have to merge the values with the same key. I have tried but not getting the expected format. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

```
 dict_list=[{'fl_metric': ('randomforest', 0.8), 'accuracy': ('randomforest', 0.9)}, {'fl_metric': ('sgdclassifier', 0.4), 'accuracy': ('sgdclassifier', 0.5)}]
```

The output should be:

```
d = {'accuracy': [('randomforest', 0.4), ('sgdclassifier', 0.5)],
 'f1_metric': [('randomforest', 0.8), ('sgdclassifier', 0.9)]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

dict_list=[{'fl_metric': ('randomforest', 0.8), 'accuracy': ('randomforest', 0.9)}, {'fl_metric': ('sgdclassifier', 0.4), 'accuracy': ('sgdclassifier', 0.5)}]
result = defaultdict(list)

for i in dict_list:
    for k, v in i.items():
        result[k].append(v)
print(result)

# --> defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'fl_metric': [('randomforest', 0.8), ('sgdclassifier', 0.4)], 'accuracy': [('randomforest', 0.9), ('sgdclassifier', 0.5)]})
```

---

or using `setdefault`

**Ex:**

```
result = {}
for i in dict_list:
    for k, v in i.items():
        result.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
print(result)

# --> {'fl_metric': [('randomforest', 0.8), ('sgdclassifier', 0.4)], 'accuracy': [('randomforest', 0.9), ('sgdclassifier', 0.5)]}
```

---